# How to get Latitude and Longitude from address using react-google-places-autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, geolocation, google-places-api, geocoding, google-places-autocomplete

I am using this package [react-google-places-autocomplete](https://tintef.github.io/react-google-places-autocomplete/docs/get-lat-lng/)
 and need latitude and longitude from address. By their documentation, there is a function but it keep says

```
"This API project is not authorized to use this API.  For more information on authentication and Google Maps JavaScript API services"
```

I enabled Geocoding and GeoLocating APIs but still getting same error. Here is my code:

```
import GooglePlacesAutocomplete, { geocodeByAddress, getLatLng } from 'react-google-places-autocomplete';

const handleAddress = (e)=>{
    setSelectedAddress(e);
    geocodeByAddress('Montevideo, Uruguay')
   .then(results => getLatLng(results[0]))
  .then(({ lat, lng }) =>
    console.log('Successfully got latitude and longitude', { lat, lng })
  );

<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
   apiKey={config.url.Google_key}
   selectProps={{
   placeholder: 'Address *',
   name:"address",
   inputValue:inputField['address'],
   onInputChange : (e)=>{setInputField({...inputField, ['address']: e})},
   onChange:(place) => {handleAddress(place.label); setErrorAddress(false);console.log(place)}
   }}
/>
```

I am using the static address to test for now. Please let me know what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
onPlaceSelected={place =>
    {
        console.log('Lat', place.geometry.location.lat())
        console.log('Lng', place.geometry.location.lng())
    }
}
```